# AngularJS Factory.XXX is not a function

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, factory

I am having fits trying to get my factory/service function to work from my controller.  I have seen many threads on this, and have tried various solutions, to no avail, so it leads me to believe I'm missing something simple. Here's the code (error message provided below):

```
    'use strict';

    var smacApp = angular.module('smacApp', ['ngRoute']);

    smacApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/login", {
                templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
                controller: "LoginController"
            })
    });   

    smacApp.factory('AuthenticationService', function() {

        var users = ["Bob", "Joe"];

        return {
            all: function() {
                return users;
            },
            first: function() {
                return users[0];
            }
        };
    });


    smacApp.controller('LoginController', function($scope,         AuthenticationService) {
        $scope.users = AuthenticationService.all();
        console.log($scope.users);
    });

    smacApp.run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$routeParams'];
    smacApp.run(function($rootScope, $routeParams) {

    });
```

The error message I am receiving is:

```
    angular.js:9778TypeError: AuthenticationService.all is not a function
        at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/smac3/app.js:61:39)
        at d (http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular.min.js:34:265)
        at Object.instantiate         (http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular.min.js:34:394)
        at http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular.min.js:66:112
        at link (http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular-        route.js:913:26)
        at J (http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular.min.js:53:345)
        at f (http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular.min.js:46:399)
        at http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular.min.js:46:67
        at http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular.min.js:47:303
        at u (http://localhost/smac3/lib/angular/js/angular.min.js:51:28)         <div ng-view="" id="container" class="ng-scope">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: sometimes it happens when you have a variable and a function with the same name. like variable 'all' and a function 'all'. well i dont see any vaiable all in your code but i just told a possibility. AuthenticationService.first() works ?

Comment: Thanks Sumeet!  Unfortunately, no joy...   TypeError: AuthenticationService.first is not a function

Comment: its weird because i use the exact same syntax and i see no mistake lol :p am thinking

Comment: It is weird!  I have stripped the code down to it's simplest form (no routing, and a single controller and factory), and I can get the code to work.  I'll start putting stuff back in slowly and see where it breaks.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the syntax for your factory is correct, but I've always written them more like this:

```
smacApp.factory('AuthenticationService', function() {

    var factory = this
    factory.users = ["Bob", "Joe"];
    factory.all = function() {
        return factory.users;
    };
    factory.first = function() {
        return factory.users[0]
    }

    return factory;
}
```

or

```
smacApp.factory('AuthenticationService', function() {

    var factory = this

    factory = {
         users: ["Bob", "Joe"],
         all: function() { return factory.users },
         first: function() { return factory.users[0] }
    }
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike!  I tried using both methods, and am getting the same error for each of them.  Is there a possibility of my injection or routing messing up the scope?  I'm fairly new to Angular, so forgive me if that sounds dumb.

Comment: I don't see any issues with scope or your injection. Double check that spelling and case are the same in all instances. I know that seems obvious, but I've spent hours thinking that wasn't the case on other issues.  Also, just for fun, try changing from a factory to a service. Although it shouldn't make a difference. If you still can't get it, post a codepen and let's have a look.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  I figured out what the problem was...  In troubleshooting, I moved my controller and service logic into my app.js, however, I still included my xxxConroler.js and xxxService.js files as <script> includes in my index.html file.  Although it seemed to be picking up the code in my app.js file, it must have been clashing with code in the included javascript files.

Comment: :) It's always something simple once you find it.